# How to choose phone number from contact list

Tags: android, contacts

I am using following code to read contacts and pick name but it allows to pull only first contact info. Please suggest any way to choose one from multiple phone numbers

```
//request to open contacts intent
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS);

//on Activity result that reads first phone number

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACTS && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + data.toString());
                uriContact = data.getData();

                retrieveContactName();
                retrieveContactNumber();
                //retrieveContactPhoto();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void pickContact() {
        Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
        pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
        startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

            // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
            // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
            // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
            // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
            // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

            // Do something with the phone number...
        }
    }
}
```